# Host does not update data from reports

Tags: c++, linux, usb, hid, raspberry-pi-pico

I'm trying to develop a custom UPS using TinyUSB on a Raspberry Pi Pico and getting it discovered by UPower on my Ubuntu host. I'm trying to signal a charging state to the host, but the host reports the battery as empty (UPower) instead of charging (Plasma Desktop battery indicator) as if there were no reports sent. How do I make UPower react to the reports? My device is detected but the host is not reading any information:

```
root@user-HP:~# upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/ups_hiddev0
  native-path:          /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/usbmisc/hiddev0
  vendor:               APC
  model:                UPS
  serial:               123456
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun, 02 Apr 2023 09:35:04 +0300 (16 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  ups
    present:             yes
    state:               empty
    warning-level:       none
    percentage:          0%
    icon-name:          'battery-empty-symbolic'
```

My expectation is that `state` would be `charging`. Device's report descriptor:

```
05 84 09 04 a1 01 09 10 a1 00 85 01 75 08 95 01 09 fd 79 01 b1 03 09 fe 79 02 b1 03 09 ff 79 03 b1 03 09 12 a1 00 85 02 05 85 75 01 95 04 17 00 00 00 00 27 01 00 00 00 09 44 09 45 09 46 09 47 81 82 95 01 75 04 81 01 c0 c0 c0

  INPUT(2)[INPUT]
    Field(0)
      Physical(Power Device.Battery)
      Application(Power Device.UPS)
      Usage(4)
        Battery System.Charging
        Battery System.Discharging
        Battery System.0046
        Battery System.0047
      Logical Minimum(0)
      Logical Maximum(1)
      Report Size(1)
      Report Count(4)
      Report Offset(0)
      Flags( Variable Absolute Volatile )
  FEATURE(1)[FEATURE]
    Field(0)
      Physical(Power Device.BatterySystem)
      Application(Power Device.UPS)
      Usage(1)
        Power Device.iManufacturer
      Report Size(8)
      Report Count(1)
      Report Offset(0)
      Flags( Constant Variable Absolute )
    Field(1)
      Physical(Power Device.BatterySystem)
      Application(Power Device.UPS)
      Usage(1)
        Power Device.iProduct
      Report Size(8)
      Report Count(1)
      Report Offset(8)
      Flags( Constant Variable Absolute )
    Field(2)
      Physical(Power Device.BatterySystem)
      Application(Power Device.UPS)
      Usage(1)
        Power Device.iSerialNumber
      Report Size(8)
      Report Count(1)
      Report Offset(16)
      Flags( Constant Variable Absolute )

Battery System.Charging ---> Sync.Report
Battery System.Discharging ---> Sync.Report
Battery System.0046 ---> Sync.Report
Battery System.0047 ---> Sync.Report
```

Parsed:

```
USAGE_PAGE (Power Device)
USAGE (UPS)
COLLECTION (Application)
  USAGE (Battery System)
  COLLECTION (Physical)
    REPORT_ID (1)
    REPORT_SIZE (8)
    REPORT_COUNT (1)

    USAGE (iManufacturer)
    STRING_INDEX (1)
    FEATURE (Constant Variable Absolute)

    USAGE (iProduct)
    STRING_INDEX (2)
    FEATURE (Constant Variable Absolute)

    USAGE (iSerialNumber)
    STRING_INDEX (3)
    FEATURE (Constant Variable Absolute)

    USAGE (Battery)
    COLLECTION (Physical)
      REPORT_ID (2)
      USAGE_PAGE (Battery System)
      REPORT_SIZE (1)
      REPORT_COUNT (4)
      LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
      LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (1)
      USAGE (Charging)
      USAGE (Discharging)
      USAGE (Fully Charged)
      USAGE (Fully Discharged)
      INPUT (Variable Absolute Volatile)

      REPORT_COUNT (1)
      REPORT_SIZE (4)
      INPUT (Constant Array)
    END_COLLECTION
  END_COLLECTION
END_COLLECTION
```

Linux doesn't recognize the `fully charged` and `fully discharged` flags. I tried removing them and only keeping the `charging` flag, as well as adding `absolute state of charge`. In main.cpp I'm sending reports:

```cpp
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "hardware/pwm.h"
#include "bsp/board.h"
#include "tusb.h"

int main() {
  board_init();
  tusb_init();

  uint32_t last_run = 0;
  uint8_t report1[] = {1, 2, 3};
  uint8_t report2[] = {0b00000001};
  while (1) {
    tud_task();

    // Send data every 50 ms
    if (board_millis() - last_run > 50 && tud_hid_ready() && !tud_suspended()) {
      last_run = board_millis();
      // tud_hid_report(1, report1, sizeof(report1)); // for some reason if I send 2 reports at once, only #1 is received on the host
      tud_hid_report(2, report2, sizeof(report2));
    }
  }
}

// Invoked when received GET_REPORT control request
// Application must fill buffer report's content and return its length.
// Return zero will cause the stack to STALL request
uint16_t tud_hid_get_report_cb(uint8_t instance, uint8_t report_id, hid_report_type_t report_type, uint8_t *buffer, uint16_t reqlen) {
  switch (report_id) {
    case 1:
      buffer[0] = 1;
      buffer[1] = 2;
      buffer[2] = 3;
      return 3;
    case 2:
      buffer[0] = 0b00000001; // Report charging state
      return 1;
    default:
      return 0;
  }
}

// Invoked when received SET_REPORT control request or
// received data on OUT endpoint ( Report ID = 0, Type = 0 )
void tud_hid_set_report_cb(uint8_t instance, uint8_t report_id, hid_report_type_t report_type, uint8_t const *buffer, uint16_t bufsize) {
  // echo back anything we received from host
  tud_hid_report(0, buffer, bufsize);
}
```

What is the correct way of sending reports: `tud_hid_get_report_cb` or using a loop and `tud_hid_report`? Reports on receiving end look correct:

```
root@user-HP:~# usbhid-dump -a 1:119 -e all
001:119:000:DESCRIPTOR         1680420804.631776
 05 84 09 10 A1 01 85 01 75 08 95 01 09 FD 79 01
 B1 03 09 FE 79 02 B1 03 09 FF 79 03 B1 03 09 12
 A1 00 85 02 05 85 75 01 95 04 17 00 00 00 00 27
 01 00 00 00 09 44 09 45 09 46 09 47 81 82 95 01
 75 04 81 01 C0 C0

Starting dumping interrupt transfer stream
with 1 minute timeout.

001:119:000:STREAM             1680420804.643196
 02 01

001:119:000:STREAM             1680420804.694348
 02 01

001:119:000:STREAM             1680420804.745391
 02 01

001:119:000:STREAM             1680420804.796426
 02 01

001:119:000:STREAM             1680420804.847433
 02 01

001:119:000:STREAM             1680420804.898256
 02 01
```

I changed `TUD_HID_DESCRIPTOR` to `TUD_HID_INOUT_DESCRIPTOR` and endpoint number to 1. Now transfers from device to host complete with success status rather than "No such file or directory". However, host sends reports using `0x81` IN endpoint rather than `0x01` OUT.

usb_descriptors.cpp:

```cpp
#include "tusb.h"
#include "report-descriptor/descriptor.hpp"

//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
// Device Descriptors
//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
tusb_desc_device_t const desc_device = {
  .bLength = sizeof(tusb_desc_device_t),
  .bDescriptorType = TUSB_DESC_DEVICE,
  .bcdUSB = 0x0200,
  .bDeviceClass = 0x00,
  .bDeviceSubClass = 0x00,
  .bDeviceProtocol = 0x00,
  .bMaxPacketSize0 = CFG_TUD_ENDPOINT0_SIZE,

  // Using APC vendor ID, because a UPS from an unknown vendor won't be detected
  .idVendor = 0x051D,
  .idProduct = 0x0003,
  .bcdDevice = 0x0100,

  .iManufacturer = 0x01,
  .iProduct = 0x02,
  .iSerialNumber = 0x03,

  .bNumConfigurations = 0x01
};

// Invoked when received GET DEVICE DESCRIPTOR
// Application return pointer to descriptor
uint8_t const *tud_descriptor_device_cb(void) {
  return (uint8_t const *)&desc_device;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
// HID Report Descriptor
//--------------------------------------------------------------------+

// Invoked when received GET HID REPORT DESCRIPTOR
// Application return pointer to descriptor
// Descriptor contents must exist long enough for transfer to complete
uint8_t const *tud_hid_descriptor_report_cb(uint8_t instance) {
  return hid_report_descriptor_test.data();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
// Configuration Descriptor
//--------------------------------------------------------------------+

enum {ITF_NUM_HID, ITF_NUM_TOTAL};

#define CONFIG_TOTAL_LEN (TUD_CONFIG_DESC_LEN + TUD_HID_INOUT_DESC_LEN)
#define EPNUM_HID 0x01

uint8_t const desc_configuration[] = {
  // Config number, interface count, string index, total length, attribute, power in mA
  TUD_CONFIG_DESCRIPTOR(1, ITF_NUM_TOTAL, 0, CONFIG_TOTAL_LEN, TUSB_DESC_CONFIG_ATT_REMOTE_WAKEUP, 100),

  // Interface number, string index, protocol, report descriptor len, EP In & Out address, size & polling interval
  TUD_HID_INOUT_DESCRIPTOR(
    ITF_NUM_HID,
    0,
    HID_ITF_PROTOCOL_NONE,
    hid_report_descriptor_test.size(),
    EPNUM_HID,
    0x80 | EPNUM_HID,
    CFG_TUD_HID_BUFSIZE,
    1
  )
};

// Invoked when received GET CONFIGURATION DESCRIPTOR
// Application return pointer to descriptor
// Descriptor contents must exist long enough for transfer to complete
uint8_t const *tud_descriptor_configuration_cb(uint8_t index)
{
  (void)index; // for multiple configurations
  return desc_configuration;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------+
// String Descriptors
//--------------------------------------------------------------------+

// array of pointer to string descriptors
char const *string_desc_arr[] = {
  (const char[]){0x09, 0x04}, // 0: is supported language is English (0x0409)
  "American Power Conversion", // 1: Manufacturer
  "UPS", // 2: Product
  "123456", // 3: Serials, should use chip ID
  "LiFePO4", // 4: Battery chemistry - unused for now
};

static uint16_t _desc_str[32];

// Invoked when received GET STRING DESCRIPTOR request
// Application return pointer to descriptor, whose contents must exist long enough for transfer to complete
uint16_t const *tud_descriptor_string_cb(uint8_t index, uint16_t langid)
{
  (void)langid;

  uint8_t chr_count;

  if (index == 0)
  {
    memcpy(&_desc_str[1], string_desc_arr[0], 2);
    chr_count = 1;
  }
  else
  {
    // Convert ASCII string into UTF-16

    if (!(index < sizeof(string_desc_arr) / sizeof(string_desc_arr[0])))
      return NULL;

    const char *str = string_desc_arr[index];

    // Cap at max char
    chr_count = strlen(str);
    if (chr_count > 31)
      chr_count = 31;

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < chr_count; i++)
    {
      _desc_str[1 + i] = str[i];
    }
  }

  // first byte is length (including header), second byte is string type
  _desc_str[0] = (TUSB_DESC_STRING << 8) | (2 * chr_count + 2);

  return _desc_str;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but you are identifying your Application Collection with a usage that is meant for a Physical Collection - 0x00840010 Battery System (Physical Collection). Try changing 0910 to 0904 - usage 0x00840004 UPS (Application Collection) - and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @aja Just tried it, no luck, unfortunately. If I change the usage to UPS and leave the application collection, UPower reports the same thing. If I leave the usage set to Battery System and change the collection to Physical, UPower doesn't enumerate the device... Which means that either I missed something in the HID spec and physical / logical collection can't be in the root, or that UPower follows some strange rules when parsing the descriptor.

Comment: Yes, the top-level collection must always be an Application Collection. That gem is only hinted at in the spec by a remark: ""Collection items
may be nested, and they are always optional, except for the top-level
application collection."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253051/discussion-between-anton-and-shellter).

Comment: I don't know how the deleted answer   below (from Baozhu Zuo) managed to get -4 downvotes  so fast, but for future readers this may help  : "
This post is hidden. It was deleted 7 hours ago by .....

 at Anton  at aja https://gist.github.com/Pillar1989/df2615ab29bf9c98f90775ce41635c10
I've perfected all the features based on your code, hope it helps, I did the test on Seeed XIAO. https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/Seeeduino-XIAO" ...

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you have a device and want to send a HID report to the host. Have you tried if the host can send a report to the device? I have a similar setup but not on a Raspberry Pi, but on the STM32G0B1 where I tried to make a port for TinyUSB for the low-level driver. In my case, the host can send a HID report, and it arrives on the device. It is a kind of heartbeat message in my case.

However, the device tries to send a similar message back to the host, but it does not arrive. I traced the data package into the device layer where it is being written into the hardware buffer. The only difference that I found is that it is getting sent out at endpoint number 1, whereas all the descriptors are sent back at endpoint number zero.

So, in my case, there might be an address mismatch accessing the right hardware registers, but I don't know. Maybe I am using the TinyUSB stack in the wrong way. Have you found a solution to your problem on the Raspberry Pi so far?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. I have never tried sending reports from host to the device, will let you know if it works out. Regarding the endpoints, 0 is the control endpoint and all others are data endpoints, so this behavior might be normal. But please take this with a grain of salt - you certainly know more than I do about how it works under the hood :)

Comment: I have tried running a few examples from the TinyUSB repo. They seem to be working fine - reports can be sent both ways. I also tried comparing their mouse example with my broken mouse test code. The difference is in the report descriptor - when a mouse has at least one button, it works, but when it's just X and Y coordinates, it doesn't. This makes me think that the UPS is missing some usages too. I just asked another, more general question on SO. Thank you.